# Exchange 2010 | Get-MailboxStatistics where clause

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I have exchange server hosting emails for multiple domains. How can I make the `Get-MailboxStatistics` cmdlet to display mailboxes and sizes only on mailboxes that end with a certain domain?

Something like `Get-MailboxStatistics WHERE EmailAddressEndsWith *emaildomain.com`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a report which shows all mailboxes which have an mail address ending on @YOURDOMAIN:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object Name, PrimarySMTPAddress, @{Name="EmailAddresses";Expression={$_.EmailAddresses -cmatch "smtp"}} | Where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*YOURDOMAIN*")}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run it like this also,

```
get-mailboxserver | get-mailbox -ResultSize 0 | where {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like '*@example.com'} | Get-MailboxStatistics | select * | Export-Csv C:\mailbox-stats.csv
```